# Ice-hockey forfeit goals

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

I want to ask, in ice-hockey general or in NHL, if a game is forfeited before it starts or at score 0:0, the winning team automatically wins by 1:0. Is this one goal counted in teams statistics in goals for? And for the loosing team in goals against?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NHL Rulebook, Rule 66](https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/assets/binary/308893668/binary-file/file.pdf):

> If the game is declared forfeited prior to its having commenced, the
> score shall be recorded as 1-0 and no player shall be credited with
> any personal statistics.
>
> If the game was in progress at the time it is declared forfeited, the
> score shall be recorded as zero for the loser and 1, or such greater
> number of goals that had been scored by it, for the winner; however,
> the players on both Clubs shall be credited with all personal statistics
> earned up to the time the forfeit was declared.

The point of recording the score is to record it as a statistic, so the answer is yes - the winning and losing team are credited with that score, but no individual player statistic is, unless there was a partially completed game in which case those statistics still count for each player (even if the team score is changed).

Comment: What if the score is 1:3 for team A and then the game is forfeited such that team B is declared as winner. Will the score be 1:0? Then after sum of stats, goals, of team A players will be greater than total goals scored by the team A? It can be lower, if there was forfeit and no player scored, but can it be greater in this situation?

Comment: So goals from forfeit loss are counted for players but not for team?

Comment: @Rikib1999 Yes, the team result is 1:0, and the players will get the credit for all four of the goals that were scored.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)